# How to use JS Array.sort() with objects with different properties

Tags: javascript, typescript, sorting

So I have these Objects:

```
let obj1 = { from: Date, to: Date }
let obj2 = { date: Date }
```

They are in an Array:

```
let arr = [ obj1, obj2 ]
```

Now I want to sort the objects inside the array with arr.sort(). But I can't figure out how to use the property "from" for the object that has this property OR "date" for the other...
I think there's an easy solution to that but I can't find anything related to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let obj1 = { from: new Date(345635), to: new Date(454567) }
let obj2 = { date: new Date(1230464) }
let arr = [ obj1, obj2 ];

const sorted = arr.sort((a, b) => ((a.from || a.date) - (b.from || b.date)))
console.log(sorted)
```

Comment: Or even `??` instead of `||`, although it doesn't matter for `Date` instances